# Passing List to Spark's parallelize() method gives compilation issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Scala and trying to execute the below code from **Learning Spark** .

```
object BasicAvg {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
         val master = args.length match {
                case x: Int if x > 0 => args(0)
                case _ => "local"
          }
          val sc = new SparkContext(master, "BasicAvg", System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"))
          val input = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4), 2)
          val result = computeAvg(input)
            val avg = result._1 / result._2.toFloat
            println(result)
     }
     def computeAvg(input: RDD[Int]) = {
          input.aggregate((0, 0))((x, y) => (x._1 + y, x._2 + 1),
                (x,y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2))
     }
}
```

**Problem :**

The statement

```
val input = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4), 2)
```

gives me below exception while compiling the code.

```
No ClassTag available for Int   BasicAvg.scala  /SparkExamples/src/main/scala/sql   line 19 Scala Problem
not enough arguments for method parallelize: (implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Int])org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int]. Unspecified value parameter evidence$1.   BasicAvg.scala  /SparkExamples/src/main/scala/sql   line 19 Scala Problem
```

But when I modify the statement as

```
val input = sc.parallelize(1 to 4, 2)
```

it works fine.

I couldn't understand what the issue is.

Thanks !!!

Comment: have you tried Seq instead of List?

Comment: yes. I tried it. Got the same issue.

Comment: Both parallelize code is working fine in spark shell. Check the output of **sc.getClass.getName**

Comment: `val input = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4))` this should work. I havent seen any second arguement for `BasicAvg` example of ***Learning spark*** book. its single arguement to parallize function that is list. second arguement is defaultparallelism by default. what do you say ? also which version of spark you are using ?

Comment: @Ankush the issue comes when running it in eclipse

Comment: @Ram The book doesn&#39;t use the second argument as you mentioned. I added that part. 
Both the ways results in the same problem.
The version of spark is 2.1.0 (with hadoop 2.7)

Comment: @Rahul try **val input = sc.parallelize[Int](List(1,2,3,4), 2)**

Comment: @ Ankush No Benefit. Also, I think for the typed list we should specify it like List[Int](1,2,3,4). What the above statement symolizes ?

Comment: Check your imports.

Comment: From Spark docs: "support for Scala 2.10 and versions of Hadoop before 2.6 are deprecated as of Spark 2.1.0, and may be removed in Spark 2.2.0". Try to run your code using Scala 2.11/2.12

Comment: I am using Spark 2.1.0 with hadoop 2.7. Scala version is 2.11.8